# Extract multiple fields from file with Ansible

Tags: json, ansible, yaml

I made an ansible playbook in order to collet data from this json file

```
{
    "validacion_user": {
        "stdout_lines": [
            "",
            "Account name: root",
            "Description: root",
            "Enabled: No",
            "Password Last Change Date: Thu Feb 14 2019 (UTC)",
            "Password Expiration Date: Not Applicable (UTC)",
            "Locked: No",
            "Role: root",
            "AD membership: 0-255",
            "Home AD: 0",
            "Day Time Access: N/A",
            "",
            "Account name: admin",
            "Description: Administrator",
            "Enabled: Yes",
            "Password Last Change Date: Thu Feb 14 2019 (UTC)",
            "Password Expiration Date: Not Applicable (UTC)",
            "Locked: No",
            "Role: admin",
            "AD membership: 0-255",
            "Home AD: 0",
            "Day Time Access: N/A",
            "",
            "Account name: user",
            "Description: User",
            "Enabled: Yes",
            "Password Last Change Date: Thu Feb 14 2019 (UTC)",
            "Password Expiration Date: Not Applicable (UTC)",
            "Locked: No",
            "Role: user",
            "AD membership: 0",
            "Home AD: 0",
            "Day Time Access: N/A",
            ""
        ]
    }
}
```

And this is the playbook that I wrote

```
---
 - name: User, Role and Status Playbook
   hosts: localhost
   gather_facts: false
   tasks: 
     - name: Obtener Usuario, rol y estado
       uri:
         url: http://192.168.1.20:80/data_broadcade.json
         validate_certs: no
         return_content: yes
       register: userbroadcade
     - debug: 
         var: userbroadcade  

     - name: Query broadcad
       set_fact:
         userdata_broadcade: "{{ userbroadcade.json.validacion_user.stdout_lines | json_query(query1) }}"
         
       vars:
         query1: "[*].{User: 'Account Name' ,Rol: Role, Estado: Enabled }"
     
         # - copy: content={{userdata_broadcade | replace('Yes','Activado') | replace('No','Desactivado')}} dest=/root/ansible/broadcade.txt

     - name: Debug
       debug:
         var: userdata_broadcade
```

But when I execute the playbook it sends a null and a Account Name string :

[image]

I think the problem is that the file aren't well structured as a Json and I've been searching about that, but I can't find how to get the Account Name, the Enabled and the Rol (The commented line is an export of the data when they works)
Does someone know how to export those fields?

(The route of the 'userdata_broadcade' are ok, because if I only put "[*]" on query1 It shows me all the data )

Comment: Which "Account Name" would you like to get? There are three of them root, admin, and user.

Answer (score 0):

> I think the problem is that the file aren't well structured as a Json

Absolutely true, however, it is *almost* yaml:

```yaml
-
  Account name: root
  Description: root
  Enabled: No
  Password Last Change Date: Thu Feb 14 2019 (UTC)
  Password Expiration Date: Not Applicable (UTC)
  Locked: No
  Role: root
  AD membership: 0-255
  Home AD: 0
  Day Time Access: N/A
-
  Account name: admin
  Description: Administrator
  Enabled: Yes
```

so you can do a little massaging to transform those lines into yaml, then you have a number of ways of reaching into those lists of dicts, either with jinja2 filters or using the JMESpath you were originally trying, if that syntax is easier for you

```yaml
  - debug:
      var: userdata_broadcade
    vars:
      userdata_broadcade: >-
        {{ userbroadcade.json.validacion_user.stdout_lines
        | map("regex_replace", "^", "  ") 
        | map("regex_replace", "^ *$", "- ") 
        | join("\n") 
        | from_yaml
        }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the file as is and put the keys into the variable *my_keys*. For example

```yaml
  vars_files:
    data_broadcade.json
  vars:
    my_keys: ['Account name', 'Role', 'Enabled']
```

Then the task below selects the required data

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_dict: "{{ my_dict|default({})|
                     combine({item: my_values}) }}"
      loop: "{{ my_keys }}"
      vars:
        my_regex: '^{{ item }}:(.*)$'
        my_replace: '\1'
        my_values: "{{ validacion_user.stdout_lines|
                       select('match', my_regex)|
                       map('regex_replace', my_regex, my_replace)|
                       map('trim')|
                       list }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_dict
```

gives

```yaml
  my_dict:
    Account name:
    - root
    - admin
    - user
    Enabled:
    - 'No'
    - 'Yes'
    - 'Yes'
    Role:
    - root
    - admin
    - user
```

and next task concatenates the required list of dictionaries

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_list_length: "{{ my_dict[my_keys.0]|length }}"
    - set_fact:
        my_list: "{{ my_list|default([]) +
                     [dict(my_keys|zip(my_values))] }}"
      loop: "{{ range(0, my_list_length|int)|list }}"
      vars:
        my_values: "{{ my_keys|
                       map('extract', my_dict, [item])|
                       list }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_list
```

gives

```yaml
  my_list:
  - Account name: root
    Enabled: 'No'
    Role: root
  - Account name: admin
    Enabled: 'Yes'
    Role: admin
  - Account name: user
    Enabled: 'Yes'
    Role: user
```